# Cannot update or install anything

Tags: repository

This is my third day on Ubuntu and i already did a mistake.
Whenever i try to update and type "sudo apt-get update "it says "E: Type '“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list
E: The list of sources could not be read."
I already removed the balenaEtcher repository from the Other software tab in the Software & Update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just removing the file it references (using the command line and `sudo`)?

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list
```

If you remove this file, it may then 'just work'.

Even if it's 'disabled' in the GUI sometimes it doesn't properly adjust the files.  Removing the list will actually remove it from the GUI as well, and if it's disabled there's no harm in removing the file.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I'm still not used to Ubuntu.

Comment: @DiamondDaemon Glad to help.  If it helped, please mark this as 'accepted' with the checkmark on the left side of the answer post, that way you can mark the answer as resolved.  And welcome to the world of Ubuntu!  :)